# Laravel query to find sum view count pf all registered users Each day in the past 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, aggregate

On my view count table, I would like to find the sum of hits by all registered users on each days in the last 7 days. Here is my table:

[image]

Here is the query that i use

```
 $RegHits = Visitor::distinct('date_visited')
->whereDate('date_visited', '>=' , Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
->whereNotNull('user_id')
->pluck('hits')
->toArray();
```

this get me an array of [15,13,6,1,4,10]

How do I get an array of sum of hits in this case, my expected result should be:

[55 , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?] for each of the last 7 days

Comment: are you blaming about that you have not enough data to "cover" all the days but it can be one day with 0 hits?

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me:

```
 Visitor::selectRaw('date_visited, Sum(hits)')
->groupBy('date_visited')
->whereNotNull('user_id')
->whereDate('date_visited', '>=' , Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
->pluck('Sum(hits)')
->toArray();
```

what I get is the sum of all registered hits per day for the last 7 days:
[55, ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?]